# Objective-C whose view is not in the window hierarchy! UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c

I have this code here that is suppose to shoot out an alert:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Device is not valid." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
[alertController addAction:ok];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but my alert does not appear and I get this error in my console log:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x134e5d350> on <ViewController: 0x135008c00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to google for a solution, but I dont understand any of them. Please Help.

Comment: What is `self`?  Are you presenting a `UIAlertController` on a view controller which is on the view stack?

Comment: Did you [try searching on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=whose+view+is+not+in+the+window+hierarchy+uialertcontroller)?

Comment: I am trying to present it to a view controller

Comment: What method of ViewController does this code exist in?  How is it being called?

Answer (score 0):

I'm tipping that you are executing this code (in a UIViewController subclass) before your view is added to the window, perhaps in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. You'll need to wait until you are definitely onscreen, try viewDidAppear:

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue sometime before. I am not sure about you but I Think your alert controller is in view will appear at this time view is not ready to show your alert controller try to do it in viewDidApper see below screenshots. [image: see error in log]

![sucessfully running][2]